# How to make a complex query in DBFlow?

Tags: android, sql, persistence, android-sqlite

I've the following models :

```
class Car {

    @Column(columnType = Column.PRIMARY_KEY_AUTO_INCREMENT, name = "id")
    long id;

    @Column(columnType = Column.FOREIGN_KEY, references = {@ForeignKeyReference(columnName = "engine", columnType = String.class,  foreignColumnName = "id")})
    Engine engine;

    // .. other columns
}


class Engine {
    @Column(columnType = Column.PRIMARY_KEY_AUTO_INCREMENT, name = "id")
    long id;


    // .. other columns
}
```

I would like to query for a Car that have a specific engine ID.

```
Engine engine = new Select().from(Engine.class).where(Condition.column(Engine$Table.ID).is(engineId).querySingle();
Car car = new Select().from(Car.class).where(Condition.column(Engine$Table.ENGINE).is(engine).querySingle();
```

Although engine is found, the Car returns null

Comment: I understand that its late to ask, but have you browsed the DB and checked if it has any rows for `Car`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the engine is defined as a foreign key within car you can just simply use a query that looks as follows.

```
new Select().from(Car.class)
.where(Condition.column(Car$Table.ENGINE_ENGINE)
.is([specific_engine_id])
.querySingle();
```

Comment: Would have been useful 5 months ago. But THANKS !